Custom end point for Wordpress single post?
I have a custom post type called customers which is just a bunch of individual customers. The pages are accessed via their post-type structure:
Eg. /customer/name-1
This is all working and loads the correct template for this post-type (single-customer.php)
Now I need to extend this and build out new functionality which will live in a new template. However, I do not want to create new pages, but instead piggy back off the single customer page where the data is saved.
Eg. /customer/name-1/workplan
When any /customer/customer-name/workplan is loaded it should:

Know the ID of the single customer
Load a new template - template-customer-workplan.php
This template will use the POST->ID to grab some custom meta fields from the single customer and populate the workplan template.

I've looked into add_rewrite_rule and add_rewrite_endpoint but am not getting what I want (tried this but don't think its correct for this use case)
    function workstreams_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^customer/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=customer&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
} add_action( 'init', 'workstreams_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 );

Does anyone have input into the correct setup and rewrites I should explore? Thanks for the read!

It's probably possible to achieve this using add_rewrite_rule(), but I prefer and recommend the seemingly forgotten add_rewrite_endpoint() function.
Tested:
// Register the endpoint.
// The `EP_ALL` may be too wide: experiment with the other values.
add_action( 'init', static function () {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'workplan', EP_ALL, 'customer_workplan' );
} );

add_filter( 'request', static function ( $vars ) {
    // Check request is for customer.
    if ( ! isset( $vars['post_type'] ) || 'customer' !== $vars['post_type'] ) {
        unset( $vars['customer_workplan'] );
    }

    // Check request is for customer's work plan.
    if ( ! isset( $vars['customer_workplan'] ) ) {
        return $vars;
    }

    // Explicitly set query var value to true.
    $vars['customer_workplan'] = true;

    return $vars;
} );

// If request is for a customer's work plan, use the template.
add_filter( 'template_include', static function ( $template ) {
    if ( ! get_query_var( 'customer_workplan' ) ) {
        return $template;
    }

    return 'template-customer-workplan.php';
} );

For a more comprehensive template handling function, I recommend the single_template_hierarchy filter:
add_filter( 'single_template_hierarchy', static function ( $templates ) {
    if ( ! get_query_var( 'customer_workplan' ) ) {
        return $templates;
    }

    $new_templates = array();

    foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
        if ( ! str_contains( $template, '-customer' ) ) {
            $new_templates[] = $template;
            continue;
        }

        $new_templates[] = str_replace( '.php', '-workplan.php', $template );
    }

    return $new_templates;
} );


Thanks, that's a very good answer. I did look into the add_rewrite_endpoint() function as well, and it was the ticket!
